# CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH - has just one path, for X11?

Tags: cmake

Running on Ubuntu 18.04, cmake version 3.18.0-rc2.
From [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH.html) I expect CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH to hold a list of directories including /usr/include, /usr/local/include, etc. :

```
Semicolon-separated list of directories specifying a search path for the find_file() and find_path() commands. By default this contains the standard directories for the current system.
```

However when I print the value of CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH from my CMakeLists.txt I get:

```
CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH: /usr/include/X11
```

Why is this?
Thanks!